# How to zip for Maybe when one of it is empty

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm trying to zip multiple sources of Maybe, but there is a possibility that one of it could be empty.

```
Maybe<ObjectA> aMaybe = Maybe.just("1");
Maybe<ObjectB> bMaybe = Maybe.empty();

return Maybe.zip(aMaybe, bMaybe, (a, b) -> {
     return c = a + b;
});
```

Unfortunately this fails when the `bMaybe` is `empty`. What I'd like is for a way to zip and have the logic such that if there is no value, still try to do something.

RxJavaVersion - 2+
(The example I added is trivial, but what I have in actual code scenario is more complicated).

What I've tried which works?
The workaround is for me to have both of these as `Single` and update the instance that is expected to be empty with a `Single<Optional>`. This doesn't sit well with me. If I'm using a `Single` I really want to expect a value to be there, going by RxJava's treatment of a `Single`.

Alternatively I can use `Maybe` with the same `Optional` case, but now I'm stuck on the fact that an async type `Maybe` is returning an `Optional`. `Maybe` already means there is maybe a value.

It seems like if there was a way I could zip with a `Maybe.empty()` and recognize that there is no value and continue doing what I want to do, everything would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, empty is error-like state in `Maybe`, that is: it breaks the flow and results in empty. It's like `NULL` in three-valued logic - one `NULL` in any expression means that everything evaluates to `NULL` (like in SQL).

`Single<Optional<>>` is not a workaround, it expresses your intent of empty being a value like any other.

`Maybe<Optional<>>` makes little sense in your case, unless your system has a clear and meaningful distinction between "no value" and "empty". `Maybe.just(Optional.empty())` is **very** different from `Maybe.empty()`, as you've already noticed.

There's no way to zip `empty` any easier than a way to zip an error. You need to use `switchIfEmpty` or `materialize` to convert the flow-breaking state into regular flow, and then process that.